antlr4 (4.13.2 clone) mvn build error during runtime test execution
all
problem during build antlr4 4.13.2 (ubuntu20, openjdk11)
"mvn -X test" output is below (this is 2nd cmdline mvn call, first was "mvn compile")
ERROR - 4 tests fail at position: DefaultMojoExecutionConfigurator.java, line 44 (excerpt below):
[DEBUG] Fork Channel [1] connected to the client.
[INFO] Running org.antlr.mojo.antlr4.Antlr4MojoTest
[ERROR] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 4, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.383 s <<< FAILURE! -- in org.antlr.mojo.antlr4.Antlr4MojoTest
[ERROR] org.antlr.mojo.antlr4.Antlr4MojoTest.importTokens -- Time elapsed: 2.716 s <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultMojoExecutionConfigurator.configure(DefaultMojoExecutionConfigurator.java:44)
    at io.takari.maven.testing.Maven331Runtime.lookupConfiguredMojo(Maven331Runtime.java:37)

.....
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   Antlr4MojoTest.importTokens:59 » NullPointer
[ERROR]   Antlr4MojoTest.importsCustomLayout:120 » NullPointer
[ERROR]   Antlr4MojoTest.importsStandardLayout:221 » NullPointer
[ERROR]   Antlr4MojoTest.processWhenDependencyRemoved:326 » NullPointer
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 4, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 



PLATFORM:
mrostron@ccycloud:~/github/antlr4$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

mrostron@ccycloud:~/github/antlr4$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.25" 2024-10-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.25+9-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.25+9-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu120.04, mixed mode, sharing)

mrostron@ccycloud:~/github/antlr4$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.9.6 (bc0240f3c744dd6b6ec2920b3cd08dcc295161ae)
Maven home: /home/mrostron/apache-maven-3.9.6
Java version: 11.0.25, vendor: Ubuntu, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.4.243-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

I am going to proceed using 4.13.2 binary download
however sending this fyi .... if anyone has guidance, would appreciate, mr
